# Django test error in command line: <model name> matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-tests

This is my `tests.py` file:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ArticleTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setup(self):
        Article.objects.create(
            article_title="title1",
            article_content="content of article",
        )

    def test_article_title(self):
        a1 = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
        article_name = a1.article_title
        self.assertEquals(article_name, 'title1')
```

But, i'm always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Django_Blog_Live\swagato_blog_site\blog_api\tests.py", line 16, in test_article_title
a1 = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
File "F:\Django_Blog_Live\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "F:\Django_Blog_Live\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
blog_api.models.Article.DoesNotExist: Article matching query does not exist.
```

And the error description is pointing at this statement: `a1 = Article.objects.get(pk=1)`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup` is not the correct name for the method. Correct name is [**`setUp`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) (notice the capital `U`). And it's **not** a `classmethod`.

There's another method called [**`setUpClass`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) which **is** a `classmethod`.

Difference between the two is that `setUp` is run before every test method whereas `setUpClass` is run once for the whole test case.

**Usage**:

Using `setUp` method is straight-forward:

```
class ArticleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create objects
        # ...
```

In Django, if you're using `setUpClass`, you also need to make a `super` call to parent class:

```
class ArticleTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass() # call parent

        # create objects
        # ...
```

Comment: Fantastic answer for such a small question.